# How can I open Cairo dock settings window from terminal?

Tags: cairo-dock

While I was tring to customize Cairo dock from its settings window, I picked up panel mode then applied it, it minimized itself on the bottom of the screen, to such extent that impossible to click it.

How can I open Cairo dock settings window from terminal to revert setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is `cairo-dock -m`. The m is for "maintenance".

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried it but in configuration window when I clicked related setting option it kept crashing. I had to remove `~/.config/cairo-dock` directory. I lost my previous settings but no problem.